# How to appropriately performFetch from NSFetchedResultsController after changes in another context?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, refresh, fetch

When I make some changes in another top layer controller with own context then I post notification to UITableViewController class for update cells. This notification calls performFetch after setting fetchedResultsController to nil. But I have seen this changes only if I reload UITableViewController entirely. I'm not using cache.
How to refresh tableView cells immediately after updating my PersistentStore?

```
- (void)performFetch {
    NSError *error = nil;

    _fetchedResultsController = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to perform fetch. Reason: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    } else {
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"orderingValue" ascending:YES];
        [request setSortDescriptors:@[sort]];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"syncStatus != %d", ObjectDeleted];
        [request setEntity:entity];
        [request setFetchBatchSize:20];
        [request setPredicate:predicate];

        NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
        _fetchedResultsController = fetchedResultsController;
        _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

**UPDATED:**
This is FetchedResultsController Delegate method:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:(ItemCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            break;
    }
}
```

Context of UITableViewController:

```
self.managedObjectContext = [[CoreDataController sharedInstance] newManagedObjectContext];
```

Context of DetailsViewController:

```
self.managedObjectContext = [[CoreDataController sharedInstance] masterManagedObjectContext];
```

CoreDataController:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)masterManagedObjectContext {
    if (_masterManagedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _masterManagedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _masterManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_masterManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            [_masterManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
        }];

    }
    return _masterManagedObjectContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)newManagedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *newContext = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *masterContext = [self masterManagedObjectContext];
    if (masterContext != nil) {
        newContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        [newContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            [newContext setParentContext:masterContext]; 
        }];
    }

    return newContext;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your complete setup involves but you do need to implement NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate protocol methods to dynamically update your tableview cells. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html

If you are using different managed object context to make updates, you will have to merge those changes as well before they are reflected in your context.

**Update1**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        addObserverForName:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                    object:nil
                     queue:nil
                usingBlock:^(NSNotification* note) {
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (note.object != moc) {
        [moc performBlock:^(){
            [moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:note];
        }];
    }
 }];
```

**Update2**

You can use the following template for NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

```
#pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
 - (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

 - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
  didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
       atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type)
   {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
              [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    default:
        break;
      }
  }


  - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
     didChangeObject:(id)anObject
         atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
       forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
        newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
  {
      switch(type)
      {
          case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
              [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray       arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
              break;

          case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
              [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
              break;

          case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
              [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
              break;

          case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
              [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
              [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
              break;
      }
  }

  - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
  {
      [self.tableView endUpdates];
  }
```

Comment: See my update. What does mean "merge those changes as well before they are reflected in your context"?

Comment: It looks like you are using the same managed object context for core data so you can ignore the merging part.

Comment: Yes, it does seem like you are using different managed object contexts. I thought you were using same context from the shared instance. You might want to take a look at: http://www.objc.io/issue-10/networked-core-data-application.html

Comment: I already have this implementation and all works good for changes in the UITableViewController's context. But I want to performFetch after changing another managed object context.

Comment: I have updated the answer with code pasted to see how to merge changes from a different managed object context

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you, it works! Now I do more understand how managed object contexts works together.